# How to change this array key based on this mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this code and query also.

```
$id_user = $this->current_user->id;
    $query_perusahaan = "SELECT
                    default_perusahaan.id_perusahaan,
                    default_perusahaan.nama_perusahaan
                    FROM
                    default_users
                    INNER JOIN default_user_perusahaan ON default_user_perusahaan.id_default_user = default_users.id
                    INNER JOIN default_perusahaan ON default_perusahaan.id = default_user_perusahaan.id_default_perusahaan
                    WHERE default_users.id = $id_user";
    $query_perusahaans = $this->db->query($query_perusahaan)->result_array();
    $list_per = array();
    $list_per[null] = "Tidak memakai perusahaan";
    foreach ($query_perusahaans as $item => $nama) {
        $list_per[$item] = $nama;
    }
        print_r($list_per);
        die();
```

This is the result :
[image: Image Result unexptected]

The result what I expect is the id_perusahaan to become the array key.
What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: `id_perusahaan` is already array key

Comment: What's your question actually?

Comment: yes, but I want it in one level of the null key? how to move it upwards @ZainFarooq

Comment: `$query_perusahaans` is likely simply a numerically indexed array, so `foreach ($query_perusahaans as $item => $nama)` of course gets you that index inside $item. `id_perusahaan` is part of _value_ of the array element, so you probably want to use `$list_per[$nama['id_perusahaan']] = $nama;`

Comment: I actually want it to be like this :

Comment: Array
(
    [] => Tidak memakai perusahaan
    [5103] => CV. YUDHA JAYA
    [5104] => CV. YUDHA JAYA
    [5105] => CV. YUDHA JAYA
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
 $list_per[$item] = $nama;
```

With

```
$list_per[$nama['id_perusahaan']] = $nama['name_perusahaan'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping the array, you can use array_column

```
$list_per = array_column($query_perusahaans, null, "id_perusahaan");
```

The third argument sets the key names.
That means array_column will return the array with no specific column (null), but change the keys to "id_perusahaan".
That results in the array being associative

Or if you want the array to be flat:

```
$list_per = array_column($query_perusahaans, "name_perusahaan", "id_perusahaan");
```